# mailx UNIX command in one line

Tags: shell, unix, mailx

What's the best way to send mail from the shell with one line of code?

```
mailx -s "subject" foo@bar.com
```

Enters into line by line entry of the body and the message is only sent with termination of Ctrl+D or '.'

Since I am accessing the system command through another program, I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
mailx -s "subject" foo@bar.com \n Body Text \n .
```

in one go.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried echoing something through a pipe to the `mailx` program? Or input redirection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mailx -s "subject" foo@bar.com <<<$'\n Body Text \n'
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to both Alfe and Joachim PileBorg, I now have two solutions! The one Alfe provided works, as does:

```
echo "body" | mailx -s "subject" foo@bar.com
```

which, though my Unix is rusty, I imagine does basically the same thing.